# ASP.NET MVC - caching pages on client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

I have code that is cached this way:

```
[OutputCache(Duration="3600", Location=OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
```

Now, I don't exactly know how this output cache works. Where exactly does it keep the copy of a page? And what are the differences between `OutputCacheLocation.Client` and `OutputCacheLocation.Browser`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Where exactly does it keep the copy of a page?

The location of where the cache is stored is determined by [`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.location%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property of the `OutputCacheAttribute`. In your case you set `Location=OutputCacheLocation.Client` so it will keep the cache on the client browser.

> And what are the differences between OutputCacheLocation.Client and
>   OutputCacheLocation.Browser?

`OutputCacheLocation.Browser` doesn't exist. It's an invalid value. The documentation of the [`OutputCacheLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation.aspx) enumeration type contains the possible values along with a description of its usage:

> - **Any** - The output cache can be located on the browser client (where the request originated), on a proxy server (or any other server)
>     participating in the request, or on the server where the request was
>     processed. This value corresponds to the HttpCacheability.Public
>     enumeration value.
> - **Client** - The output cache is located on the browser client where the request originated. This value corresponds to the
>     HttpCacheability.Private enumeration value.
> - **Downstream** - The output cache can be stored in any HTTP 1.1 cache-capable devices other than the origin server. This includes
>     proxy servers and the client that made the request.
> - **Server** - The output cache is located on the Web server where the request was processed. This value corresponds to the
>     HttpCacheability.Server enumeration value.
> - **None** - The output cache is disabled for the requested page. This value corresponds to the HttpCacheability.NoCache enumeration value.
> - **ServerAndClient** - The output cache can be stored only at the origin
>     server or at the requesting client. Proxy servers are not allowed to
>     cache the response. This value corresponds to the combination of the
>     HttpCacheability.Private and HttpCacheability.Server enumeration
>     values.