# Can a Partial View be cached on the client side in an asp.net mvc website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, partial-views, outputcache

I have a large menu with lots of pictures that appears on top of every page.

What I thought was to put my menu in a `PartialView` and store it in `OutputCache`. But then, all the menu content still have to make the trip from server to client on every new page load.

Would it be possible to set the `OutputCacheLocation` for a `PartialView` to `Client`?

I would be surprised if this was possible, but then what would happen if I do set the cache location of a `PartialView` to `Client`? Would it be ignored or cached on the sever?

Answer (score 0):

For caching on client side you can use the attribute

`[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Client)]`

You can read more here - [ASP.NET MVC - caching pages on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609291/asp-net-mvc-caching-pages-on-client-side)

Comment: Thanks... yes I had read this article... My question is, is it actually possible to cache a partial view on client side.

Comment: If you are asking a boolean answer definitely answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks - do you know how all this is happening? My understanding is when a request is sent to the server, the server builds the HTML response and send it back to the client. How would the server know that part of this HTML Response (PartialView) already exists on the client, and it should leave that part empty? and what would happen if client suddenly clears the cache? I don't realize how this is actually possible.