# Client-Side Caching in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Let's say I want to store the user's First and Last name in the client-side cache (browser) which will be fetched throughout the site. This will then expire after some time. How can I do this using ASP.NET MVC (i.e. storing and fetching data in the cache through the controller)?

I tried using HttpContext.Current.Cache but that apparently uses server-side caching. So what happened was when users logged in at the same time, they were getting a different first and last name.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - caching pages on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609291/asp-net-mvc-caching-pages-on-client-side)

Comment: Hi Amy. I'm trying to store and fetch pieces of data (e.g. first and last name) in the cache instead of an entire page. How can this be done using OutputCache?

Comment: If it's small information then, Why don't you go for cookie or else session ?

Comment: @AdrianValenzuela its the same thing.  just replace the word "page" with "data".  its treated the same way.  `OutputCache` caches the *result* of the action method.  If the result is a page, it caches a page.  If the result is data, well, guess what happens.

Comment: Use javascript `localStorage` method `setItem()` and `getItem()` but it will not automatically expire after some time.